# Cannot delete default content from document set

Tags: document-set

I am attempting to delete one of the default content items from a document set from the document settings page:
[image: Document Set Default Contents]

After clicking "OK" at the bottom of the page I get an error page, and the server admins were kind enough to provide me the logs, which revealed the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException: urlOfFile  Parameter name: Specified value is not supported for the urlOfFile parameter.
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileCollection.get_Item(String urlOfFile)
    at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DefaultDocumentCollection.Remove(String name)
    at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.Pages.DocSetSettings.RemoveDefaultContent()
    at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.Pages.DocSetSettings.Update(Object o, EventArgs e)
    at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
    at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
    at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint
```

)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I caused the issue myself. I renamed a file in *siteUrl*/_cts/*DocSetName*/.

The proper approach would have been to delete the default content from the document set settings page, then upload a file with the corrected name.